# Remainder for a GP

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

What is the remainder of  : $\sum_{i=0}^{2019} 3^i$  divided by $3^4$ ?

I know that $$\sum_{i=0}^{2019} 3^i = \frac{3^{2020}}{3-1} = \frac{3^{2020}}{2} $$

so  $$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{2019} 3^i}{3^4} = \frac{3^{2016}}{2}$$

how do I proceed from here? I tried running a program in python on it but I think the number is too big

Comment: That ratio isn't _quite_ so tidy: your application of the finite geometric sum formula should produce  $$  \sum_{i=0}^{2019} 3^i  \ = \ 1·\frac{1 \ - \ 3^{2020}}{1-3} \ = \ \frac{3^{2020} \ - \ 1}{2} \ \ . $$  The subsequent division by $ \ 3^4 \ $ is consequently a bit less simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Your sum is $3^0+3^1+3^2+3^3+3^4(3^0+3^1+...+3^{2015})$.

Comment: Ah I see! Then I will have $3^{-4} + 3^{-3} + 3^{-2} + 3^{-1}$ as the remainder portion in decimals which I then multiply with $3^{4}$ for the remainder. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you will get $3^0+3^1+3^2+3^3=40$ as the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

The answer **Shubham Johri** provides is definitely the quickest approach and is the way we would think of that sum in terms of modular arithmetic (using mod $ \ 81 \ $ here).  From where you were (once the correction is made to the geometric sum), you could write
$$ \ \frac{3^{2020} - 1}{2 \ · \ 3^4} \ \ = \ \  \frac{(3^{2020} - 3^4) \ + \ (3^4 \ - \ 1)}{2 \ · \ 3^4} \ \ = \ \ \frac{3^{2016} - 1}{2} \ + \ \frac{80}{2 \ · \ 81} \ \ . $$
The numerator in the first term is a product of $ \ 2016 \ $ odd factors less $ \ 1 \  : \ $ the product is therefore odd and the numerator is even, making the first term an integer.  The second term is the even numerator $ \ 80 \ = \ 2^4 · 5 \ $   divided by $ \ 2 \ $ and a product of four $ \ 3 $ 's, so this ratio is $ \ \frac{40}{81} \ $ "in lowest terms".  The remainder in the specified division is thus $ \ 40 \ \ . $